# Subtract two timecodes in bash, for use in ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I am running ffmpeg in terminal on a mac, to trim a movie file losslessly using the following in bash:

```
startPosition=00:00:14.9
endPosition=00:00:52.1
ffmpeg -i mymovie.mov -ss $startPosition -to $endPosition -c copy mymovie_trimmed.mov
```

But that doesn't seek the nearest keyframe and causes sync issues. See here: https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/pull/13

So I need to rearrange my code like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss $startPosition -i mymovie.mov -t $endPosition -c copy mymovie_trimmed.mov
```

(the -to property seems to get ignored, so I am using -t (duration) instead). My question is how can I reliably subtract the $startPosition variable from the $endPosition to get the duration?

EDIT: I used [oguz-ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail)'s suggestion with using **gdate** instead of date (and *brew install coreutils*):

```
startPosition=00:00:10.1
endPosition=00:00:50.1
x=$(gdate -d"$endPosition" +'%s%N')
y=$(gdate -d"$startPosition" +'%s%N')
duration=$(bc -lq <<<"scale=1; ($x - $y) / 1000000000")
```

This gives me output of *40.1*, how would I output it as *00:00:40.0* ?

Comment: Do you need microseconds too or seconds are enough? I.e should duration be 37 or 37.2?

Comment: I can make do with seconds, though it would be good to have it work for microseconds for future projects

Comment: Do you have GNU date installed on your system?

Comment: I'm not sure, is there a way to find out?

Comment: Do you use a Mac? they come with BSD date

Comment: Yes terminal on a mac. OS 10.12.6

Comment: Then you should either install GNU date, or use awk to make the conversion. An example using awk: `echo "$startPosition" | awk -F: '{ print $1*3600 + $2*60 + $3 }'`. Since I don't have a Mac around, I can't post a complete answer though.

Comment: Always place `-ss` and `-to` on the same side, so both on input or on output.

Comment: @Gyan It's to prevent sync issues regarding keyframes. See link: https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/pull/13